# An identity relating sum of number of partitions to sum of number of parts

Tags: number-theory, mathematical-physics, integer-partitions

I encountered this identity while studying about the Kac determinants in CFT.

$$\sum_{\{n_1 + \cdot \cdot \cdot + n_k \}} k = \sum_{pq \le N} P(N-pq)$$

Here $P(N-pq)$ is the number of partitions of $N-pq$.  $p,q$ are positive c-prime integers such that their product is less than equal to $N$, and $k$ is the number of parts in a partition of $N$. So  $N=n_1 + n_2 + \cdot \cdot + n_k$ for some $k$ ($5=3+2 \implies k=2$), this sum is taken over all possible tuples.

How do I prove this identity?

I am a physics undergrad, so assumption of minimal prerequisites to this problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are $p$ and $q$?

Comment: @Vladimir: $p,q$ are integers greater than 0 such that their product is less than equal to $N$. Thanks for asking. Question edited.

Comment: @Vladimir: sorry p and q are also co-prime.

Comment: Without the "coprime" requirement, this seems to be https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864176/proof-of-an-identity-about-integer-partition . Are you sure you want $p$ and $q$ coprime?